# Incorrect parameter in TextEdit in the array

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, android-edittext

sorry for my bad English. I use the google translate.
I just program a game for android.
with my problem I give ingame checks made in an array.
it is in this case the value of the checks displayed.
then the amount of the checks is in a textedit displayed and pay a button for.
when the button is pressed, to be disbursed during textedit the value entered.
However, only the total fees paid and no partial amount.
my problem is that is not handed over to the edited text.
it is only the value passed is displayed from the beginning.
Why? where is my mistake?
I marked the character area with a number of ??.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(jObject.has("error")){
                        no_schecks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else {
                        no_schecks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        final int scheckid = jObject.getInt("scheckid");
                        final String condition = jObject.getString("condition");

                    scheckx = new Scheck(condition, scheckid );

                    ll = (TableLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    scheckLocalStore.storeScheckData(scheckx);

                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(getArguments());
                    View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_scheckx,
                            null);

                    TextView conditions = (TextView) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.condition);
                    conditions.setText(" " + scheckx.condition + " ₢  ");
                    conditions = new TextView(getActivity());
                    row.addView(conditions);


Log.i("info", "start?????????????????????????????");

                    EditText setconditions = (EditText) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.setcondition);
                    setconditions.setText(scheckx.condition);
                    setconditions = new EditText(getActivity());
                    row.addView(setconditions);

Log.i("info", "end?????????????????????????????");


                    Button btnSetCondition = (Button) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnSetCondition);
                        final String thisCondition = scheckx.condition;
                        final String thisId = Integer.toString(scheckx.scheckid);
                        final int thatId = scheckx.scheckid;


Log.i("info", "start?????????????????????????????");

                        //final String thatCondition = setconditions.getText().toString();
                        final String thatCondition = ((EditText) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.setcondition)).getText().toString();

Log.i("info", "end?????????????????????????????");


                    scheckLocalStore = new ScheckLocalStore(super.getActivity());
                    btnSetCondition.setId(btnSetCondition.getId());
                    btnSetCondition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            switch (v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.btnSetCondition:

                                    Log.i("info", "SCHECKKRAM " + thatCondition + " " + thisCondition);
                                    Scheck scheck = new Scheck(uid, usersecu, thatId, thisCondition);
                                    executeScheck(scheck, thatCondition, thisId);
                                    //objFragment = new activity_bank_main();
                                    break;
                            }
                            if(objFragment != null){
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                                        .commit();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //row.setLayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    row.addView(theInflatedView);
                    ll.addView(row, i);
                }
            }
```

Comment: special thanks for the edit sergey glotov

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating your EditText 2 times and that's why the value you set is lost -

```
                    EditText setconditions = (EditText) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.setcondition); // 1st time
                    setconditions.setText(scheckx.condition);
                    setconditions = new EditText(getActivity()); // 2nd time
                    row.addView(setconditions);
```

Remove  `setconditions = new EditText(getActivity());` statement and   you are good to go !!

Comment: if I do that crashes the app.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call RemoveView () on the child's parent first.

if I ((ViewGroup) setconditions.getParent ()). RemoveView (setconditions) use EditText not appear.